# Objective C how to add textfield into navigation bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to add a textfield into a navigation bar, but it doesn't show up in the simulator.  I do it as follows inside viewdidload:

```
UITextView *textField = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 170, 44)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: i didn't add any text to it. i wanted to overlay it with a search icon (magnifying glass) but couldn't figure out if i could do that without adding a png icon.  The default search bar is more rounded, but i wanted it to look more like a text field.

Thanks!
David

Answer (score 4):

i have done it in this way. i know that you have got to the answer uptil now 
but still this will helpful to someone else so
this can be done as follows

```
  -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     imgVw =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(68, 7, 180, 28)];
     [imgVw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldBackground.png"]];
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgVw]; 

      textfieldTxt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78, 11, 170, 25)];
      textfieldTxt.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      [textfieldTxt setAutocorrectionType:UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo];
       textfieldTxt.delegate = self; 
      [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:textfieldTxt]; 

    }
```

please don't forgot to remove from superview, when viewdidunload

```
 - (void)viewDidUnload
     {
     [super viewDidUnload];
     [textfieldTxt removeFromSuperview];
     [imgVw removeFromSuperview];
  }
```

thanks

Comment: This is bad, as the `navigationController.navigationBar` does not belong to the current view controller. You better should put it into a custom bar button or in the title view. http://www.iphonegamezone.net/118/