# Add UITextField to title view of navigation item

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield

How do you add a text field to the title view of a navigation item and have it sized correctly?

It works fine if I do this with a search bar like this but I don't know how to get a text field to size itself in the same way as a search bar.

```
myViewController.navigationItem.titleView = [UISearchBar new];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C how to add textfield into navigation bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073503/objective-c-how-to-add-textfield-into-navigation-bar)

Comment: Btw, this works for me: `UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 21.0)];
self.navigationItem.titleView = tf;                                                      [tf becomeFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As my comment suggested, try the following, which seems to me is what you're after.

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, 21.0)];

self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;

[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  The text field is only a few pixels in width.  I'm creating everything programmatically.

Comment: As you see above, it is all programmatic, no?

Comment: Ok, I was trying to do this from the app delegate.  This works if you do this from -viewDidLoad in the view controller.

Comment: Yeah, that's normally how you would do things

Comment: @BerryBlue I'm curious on where did you put it at first

Comment: Thank you very much, It works, but when I rotate device, the width becomes wrong. How can I fix that problem ?

Comment: @klcjr89 Maybe you should add information about where to put the code, e.g. viewDidLoad. Then you might get more upvotes. From the comments above I gather that it's not totally clear where to put the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class: ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.delegate = self
navigationItem.searchController?.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController?.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = "Enter text here..."
```