# Textfield in navigation bar using an XIB

Tags: ios, swift4.2

I am trying to add a textfield to navigation bar for search functionality. I don't have any idea how to do this. Can any one help me to do this?

Comment: you can use `uisearchbar` for your concept,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add UITextField to title view of navigation item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976109/add-uitextfield-to-title-view-of-navigation-item)

Answer (score 0):

You can add textfield in navigation bar as follow.

```
 extension UIViewController {

    func  setTextFieldInNavigationBar(withDelegate delegate: UITextFieldDelegate? = nil) {
      let txtField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 30))
      txtField.placeholder = "Enter some text"
      txtField.delegate = delegate

      //set other property as required
      navigationItem.titleView = txtField
  }

  //it will return UITextField, if there is TextField set in titleView in navigation bar
  var navTextField: UITextField? {
    return navigationItem.titleView as? UITextField
  }

}
```

You can call this in view controller as follow.

If you want to implement delegate then use this...

```
setTextFieldInNavigationBar(withDelegate: self)
```

or if you do not want to implement delegate then use this...

```
setTextFieldInNavigationBar()
```

You can use textfield in following way in `UIViewController`

```
print(navTextField?.text)
```